# read data from PCAP and print details when conditions met

Tags: pcap, tcpdump, packet-capture

I have assignment to Read packets from a file and output the details of those packets having.
*Do not fragment(DF)* flag set for IP header and *SYN and ACK* flags
set (together) for TCP header (all the three flags should be set). For
packets qualifying the above condition print the following:

- Packet number
- Source IP address and Source port number
- Destination IP address and Destination port number

I have done packet capture but not able to print values matching condition of all 3 flag set from that PCAP file

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Starting ")
for packet in PcapReader(filename):
   if packet[IP].flags == 'DF' and packet[TCP].flags == 'S' and packet[TCP].flags == 'A':
       print("Source IP address = {} , source port number = {} , destination IP addr = {} , destination port number = {} ".format(packet[IP].src,packet[TCP].sport,packet[IP].dst,packet[TCP].dport))
else:
   print("Finishing. ")
```